# Is there any way to stop the game from putting me in auto-run?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I prefer to hold the shift key to run, and so every time I start the game, I hit Caps Lock to disable auto-run. However, I find it always finds opportunities to re-enable itself. Sometimes I will go through a door that has a loading screen, and I'm auto-running when I come out the other site. Other times I will speak to an NPC and will be running after the conversation has ended.

I tried finding an option in the menu but couldn't. Is there some kind of configuration that would allow me to disable auto-run altogether so that the game doesn't do it for me?

Comment: Why do you need to push caps lock to disable auto-run in the start? What happens if you change the auto-run key of Skyrim itself?

Comment: Because the game sets my character to auto-run automatically. I haven't tried changing the key but I presume that the game would still set me on auto-run automatically at every loading. I'll try tonight.

Comment: Man... how can you bear anything but auto run.  Perhaps my character has a bad knee, but his walk speed is glacial.

Comment: Yeah, why would anyone want to walk by default?

Answer (score 6):

You can change the default autorun state from on to off by editing the game's preference file, which is located in:

```
My Documents/My games/Skyrim/SkyrimPrefs.ini
```

In there, you can find the section **[Controls]** which has a setting

```
bAlwaysRunByDefault=1
```

Change it to:

```
bAlwaysRunByDefault=0
```

To turn autorun off by default.

Comment: For some reason that had no effect (I restarted the game). I'm thinking this might be a bug. I'll leave the question open to see if anyone else has anything to add and then I'll accept your answer because it *should* be the answer even though it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you exit the game before making the changes and saving the config file? Because it works for me when I do it like that.

Comment: Yeah, I completely closed the game, modified it, and started it back up. I'll try again tonight, maybe it somehow reverted.

Comment: As soon as you do what causes it to glitch it still defaults back to always run

Answer (score 3):

The `bAlwaysRunByDefault` suggestion is useful for when you first start up the game, but the problem isn't what the default is, it's the game toggling your current setting without prompting. This a known issue caused by doing certain things while holding shift. Holding shift while talking to an NPC causes it very consistently. Going through a loading screen does it inconsistently. I've also heard of people experiencing it when getting a killing blow animation.

Edit: [Nexus Thread discussing the issue for reference](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/489930-toggle-always-run-is-killing-me/)